# Multiple scheduler with Grails Quartz plugin

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have an application using Grails Quartz plugin. I need to have two jobs to have multiple instances running, but have separate limitation on number of threads to be used for each job. As far as I understand, I need separate Thread Pools, which is possible by having separate schedulers. However, I cannot figure out how to create multiple schedulers with Quartz plugin.

Comment: When you mean multiple instances running are you talking about using different triggers to start the job multiple times?

Comment: Yes, two jobs I mention are triggerred multiple times concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use different triggers to start the job multiple times. this works for me.

```
class MyJob {

    static triggers = {
        cron name: 'trigger1', cronExpression: "0 30 12 ? * WED"
        cron name: 'trigger2', cronExpression: "0 30 12 ? * SAT"
    }

    def execute() {

        // execute task, do your thing here
        println "Job executed"
    }
}
```

Finally, about concurrent tasks.
This is from the plug-in page:

> By default Jobs are executed in concurrent fashion, so new Job
>   execution can start even if previous execution of the same Job is
>   still running.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz plugin 2.0.13

According to the official [documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html) :

> Multiple triggers per job are allowed.

For instance,

```js
class MyJob {
  static triggers = {
    simple name:'simpleTrigger', startDelay:10000, repeatInterval: 30000, repeatCount: 10
    cron name:'cronTrigger', startDelay:10000, cronExpression: '0/6 * 15 * * ?'
    custom name:'customTrigger', triggerClass:MyTriggerClass, myParam:myValue, myAnotherParam:myAnotherValue
  }
```