# Grails Quartz - How to conbine similar two jobs into one job?

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have to similar two jobs and want to conbine the two jobs into one job.

How can I conbine AJob and BJob into a new Job?

In other words, I want to refactor AJob.groovy and BJob.groovy into one class NewJob.groovy.

AJob.groovy

```
class AJob {
    def testService
    static triggers = {
      cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "0 0 6 * * ?"
    }
    def group = "MyGroup"
    def description = "A job with hello"
    def execute() {
        testService.hello("hello")
    }
}
```

BJob.groovy

```
class BJob {
    def testService
    static triggers = {
      cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "0 0 7 * * ?"
    }
    def group = "MyGroup"
    def description = "B job with goodbye"
    def execute() {
        testService.hello("goodbye")
    }
}
```

TestService.groovy

```
class TwitterService {
    def hello(message){
        print message
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by combine? What are you trying to do? What are you trying to avoid? You need to provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish and what problems you are facing in doing that.

Comment: My English is not good. I changed the question to How can I conbine AJob and BJob into NewJob? Is it good English?

Comment: In other words, I want to refactor AJob.groovy and BJob.groovy into one class NewJob.groovy.

Comment: Their both at different times  ? otherwise you could execute both within same execute block and have 1 job. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417215/how-to-configure-quartz-triggers-in-grails-to-allow-different-schedules-for-test Take a look here - you could adapt it. trying to define two would try to do it twice.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362058/multiple-scheduler-with-grails-quartz-plugin

Comment: As a quick response, they are at different times. I will read your suggestion page after this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the only reason to do it this way (versus having Cron call both at the same time) would be to somehow synchronize them, in order to guarantee  A is called after B.  The most obvious solution would be as alluded to above:

```
class NewJob{
    def execute() {
        testService.hello("hello")
        testService.hello("goodbye")
    }
}
```

If for some reason these are asynchronous calls (and you still want to synchronize), you would have to use the callback on the thread or create separate threads and somehow inject the dependency.    The only reason not to do this, would be if you somehow needed to record the dependent injection of the quartz job.    More details?